# Suitable place to initialise the Swift member variable

Tags: ios, swift

Take my code as an example:

```
class MyView: UIView {

    var labelText : UILabel

    init() {

        // ****** Place 1 ******

        // the width of my view is fixed
        super.init(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, CGFloat(200), 0))

        // ****** Place 2 ******
```

I normally can initialize the label in **Place 1** or **Place 2**. But both are not perfect. If the view itself is not initialised if I initialise the label at **Place 1**. And I got the following error message if I init the label at **Place 2** so that I need to declare the label as optional.

> Property 'self.labelText' not initialized at super.init call

The problem of optional variable is that I have to use labelText! everywhere which makes the code a bit confusing.

Any better idea? Thanks

Comment: You can initialize `labelText` in place 1 and then initialize it again in place 2, but that works for `var`s only. A little more processing and more work for ARC, but I guess cleaner code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should initialise the variable at 'place 1', and act upon it in 'place two', e.g.

```
class MyView: UIView {

    let labelText : UILabel

    init() {

        labelText = new UILabel()

        // the width of my view is fixed
        super.init(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, CGFloat(200), 0))

        addSubView(labelText)
   }

}
```

Also, in most cases I would expect this label to be a constant, hence the use of `let` above.